# Why I cannot solve this limit problem this way?

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x\to -1} \ \, \frac{1}{{1+x}}  \left( \frac{1}{{x+5}}+ \frac{1}{{3x-1}}  \right)  $

As, the limit is not   of the form$\  \frac{0}{{0}}  $ so, put $\  x  $ as $\ -1 $ we get Answer $\  0$ .
What is wrong in this?

Comment: How is it not of the form $\frac{1}{0} \times 0$?

Comment: @CalvinLin yeah, edited'

Comment: The closing voter made me curious: "but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." Really? Or is this the new whatever-does-not-fit-closing-reason?

Comment: @joeyrohan Why would you plug in 0 for $x$ while taking a limit as $x\rightarrow-1$?

Comment: @nrpeterson: I am hoping that that was a typo and they intended to "put $x$ as $-1$".

Comment: I think the closing voter was (rather naively) closing on the basis of the question in the title. I do think the OP should change the title to something referencing the question though.

Comment: @nrpeterson I made a mention of that originally, and OP replied with "edited" and so I removed the comment. However, it has not been edited in.

Comment: @DanielRust I am fairly confident the title question can be answered on the basis of precise facts.

Comment: @julien Either I'm missremembering the title of the question or it was edited to include the words 'this way'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write the limit as
$$
\frac{\frac1{x+5}+\frac1{3x-1}}{x+1}
$$
it becomes of the form $\frac00$. From here try combining the fractions in the numerator:
$$
\frac{\frac{4x+4}{(x+5)(3x-1)}}{x+1}
$$
now you can cancel the pieces that go to $0$ and try to plug in $x=-1$.

Answer (score 3):

$\lim\limits_{x\to -1}\frac{1}{x+1}.\frac{4x+4}{(x+5)(3x-1)}=\lim\limits_{x\to -1}\frac{4}{(x+5)(3x-1)}=\frac{-1}{4}$

Comment: similar, but slightly different, approach. Quite valid. (+1)